# DockerHub tag for running Splunk on CentOS 7

Tags: dockerfile, centos7, splunk

Does anyone know the tag I should use for running Splunk on CentOS 7? According to the following GitHub link, this host OS is supported:
https://github.com/splunk/docker-splunk/tree/develop/base/centos-7

I've searched DockerHub (https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/splunk), but the closest tag I found is listed below:
splunk/splunk:7.2.9-redhat

Answer (score 0):

`docker pull splunk/splunk` will be sufficient to run Splunk in Docker on CentOS.